# Unable to reach self hosted Ubuntu gitlab's login page from web browser remotely

Tags: login, remote, gitlab

I am new to ubuntu as well as gitlab. This is my first time setting up the self-hosted Ubuntu Gitlab Server in my own laptop.

**Problem Statement : Unable to reach gitlab's login page from web browser remotely.**

**I have done the following steps:**

1) Register DDNS from No-IP.com

2) Setup DDNS in my router.
[Router Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9oNF.png)

3) Done port forwarding setting in my router. [Port forwarding settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIhhY.png)

4) Changed my internet connection to dynamic public IP

5) I not sure what should keyin for external url in gitlab.rb file. I tried 192.168.1.108, 192.168.1.107, xxx.ddns.net, public IP, 192.168.1.108:22, xxx.ddns.net:22. All settings are unable for me to login into gitlab server remotely from another laptop.

6) Disabled laptop firewall.

**Information**

1) Ubuntu IP : 192.168.1.108 (Get from ifconfig)

2) My Laptop IP : 192.168.1.107 (Get from ipconfig)

3) I run the ubuntu virtual box from my laptop.

4) I can reach the gitlab login page from my own laptop using http://192.168.1.108 (Works fine)

5) I can remote access to ubuntu server using PUTTY from another laptop that is connected to my phone's hotspot (purposely to separate from my laptop and ubuntu server network). I can access using both ddns address (xxx.ddns.net) or public IP with port number 22.

6) If another laptop is connected to same network with my laptop, I able to reach the gitlab login page using IP 192.168.1.108. (works fine)

7) I tried to access my ubuntu gitlab server from another laptop (different network) using "Public IP:22", "xxx.ddns.net:22", "Public IP", and "xxx.ddns.net". All return fail result and the message from web browser is  "The connection to the website was reset. Error code : INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE".

Hope someone can help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Is the port forwarding setting not done probably.

I should port forward 80 to 192.168.1.108 port 80.

Now my server is working perfectly.

Thanks